# Google Vision not always including pagesWithMatchingImages in web detection responses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm sending web detection requests like this to the Google Vision API.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "<base 64 encoded image>"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "maxResults": 50,
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The requests are being sent to `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<my key>`.

The part of the response I need is pagesWithMatchingImages, so I can see which pages have the given image.  This works for most of the images I've tried, but not for images that contain text.  If the image is a common logo that includes text, for example, then the API doesn't include pagesWithMatchingImages in the response.

How can I get a list of pages with matching images for images that include text?

Here's are some samples of images that are used on a lot of web pages, but don't have pagesWithMatchingImages in the API response:

[image: Adobe logo]

[image: Amazon logo]

[image: Nike logo]

[image: FedEx logo]

[image: Sony logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing with the Google Vision API WEB_DETECTION feature seems to be an issue detected by the  Google Vision API team, they seem to be investigating more about it and they will post the updates within the [Public Issue Tracker post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128345266).

One of the reasons the WEB_DETECTION feature does not responds with the pagesWithMatchingImages seems to be related to the transparency in PNG images, adding a white background might help the WEB_DETECTION feature according to the post, but does not warranty the accuracy in the response

The [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) is used for reporting bugs and feature requests of the Google Cloud products, by indicating that you are affected by the same issue it can help to bring more visibility on it and expedite the resolution.

Comment: That request asks Google to parse the text, which it can do, but that's not helpful for me.  The data I need is the list of pages with matching images (pagesWithMatchingImages).  That field is missing from the API response.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding of your use of case, I will edit the answer with the one that works for your case.

Comment: Please read my original question again.  I can only get the API to work if the logo doesn't include any text.  I need it to work with or without text in the logo.

Comment: The transparent background is in interesting idea.  I did some testing with logos that don't have transparent backgrounds, and I'm seeing the same results.  Logos that have text (Amazon, FedEx, etc.) consistently result in Google omitting pagesWithMatchingImages from the response, whether they're transparent or not.

If I use the Bing API with the same images, it returns the results I need.  So, while I'd rather get this to work with Google, the best solution may be to use Bing.

Comment: I modified my previous answer so it makes clear that the issue you are facing was detected by the Google Vision API team and they are working on it, if everyone else has the same issue they can refer to the Public Issue Tracker thread and start to get notifications about its resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add the `LOGO_DETECTION` type under features.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "<base 64 encoded image>"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "maxResults": 50,
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
        }
        {
          "type": "LOGO_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help.  Here's a sample image you can experiment with:  https://cloudboost.io/images/adobe.png

Comment: If you are dealing with logos, I suggest using LOGO_DETECTION feature instead. I modified my original answer so you can try it out as well.

Comment: LOGO_DETECTION does a great job of identifying the logo, but that's not what I need.  It still doesn't give me a list of web pages that use the logo (pagesWithMatchingImages).